# Bootstrap Tooltip not working on input field

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I,m using tooltip in my Rails app but it not working on input field as my code is:

```
  %input#main-search{:name => "query", :placeholder => "search all 
    items", :rel => "tooltip", :title => "Search All Items", :type => "text"}
  :javascript
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('input[title]').tooltip({placement:'bottom'});
    });
```

I also use:

```
$('#main-search').tooltip({'trigger':'focus'});
```

Its not work for input field but for label it works fine. how can  I inable tooltip for input field?

Comment: What does the generated mark up look like?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here is valid HTML  markup for tooltip:

```
<input data-toggle="tooltip" title="tooltip on second input!" type="text" placeholder="Focus me!" name="secondname"/>
```

And here is jQuery with right placement for tooltip and trigger on focus:

```
$('input[type=text][name=secondname]').tooltip({ /*or use any other selector, class, ID*/
    placement: "right",
    trigger: "focus"
});
```

[Always look at official docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips).

And here is working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/N9vN8/69/

Comment: Thanks for the response @Miljan . I already check this code and official docs,but it not working for me. But if I use 'data-original-title' instead of 'title' and in .js file $("[rel=tooltip]").tooltip({trigger: "focus"});..Its works. I don't know why above code not working?

Comment: @rubydev, Twitter Bootstrap uses HTML5 `data` attribute (more precisely older versions used `data-original-title`), so you must use data attributes in one way or another. And second way is like in my solution. But, I'm not sure about `rel` attribute in input tag like in your case, I think it's not semantic. Because of that, I've avoided that and used `data-toggle` and then in js you can use any selector (class, id, input name)...

Answer (score 1):

It is simpler to activate it to all inputs or glyphicons where you want to use a tooltip by just typing the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
                $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
            });
</script>
```

Inside an input:

```
<input data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Your awesome tip!" type='text' class="form-control" name="name"  placeholder="placeholder" maxlength="10"/>
```

Inside a glyphicon:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Open calendar"></span>
```

This way you don't need to worry about any IDs when using tooltips in several inputs in the same form.

Source: [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips).